# UI pixel bug in Office 16

Tags: excel, user-interface, error-handling, ms-word, office365

my first post here, i'm having an issue with Office 16 just downloaded on my Windows 11, when i open any app from Office suite i get some strange pixel flashing errors on my UI (ONLY IN OFFICE ALL OTHER PROGRAMS RUN SMOOTHLY).
I already tried to:

- Disable GPU aceleration
- Unistall/reinstall office suite
- Unistall any previous Office version i had

I had to take pics of the screen with my mobile phone because screenshots/screen recording didnt show the bugs in the records.

[image: Bug1]

[image: Bug2]

anyone has an idea what the reason of this issue might be???

Comment: Random guess:  Try updating your graphics driver.